# grunt-bowercopy 2 profiles dev and prod

Tags: gruntjs, bower, minify

Hi what would be the best way to have 2 "profiles" on a bowercopy task on Grunt, one for dev and another for production?

On the dev, I wish to copy all non minified versions,and on the production, the minified ones.

I tried using grunt.option to create somehow a suffix (either min.js or .js), but couldn't figure out yet a way of doing without much repetition.

I don't want, at this stage, to use uglify either, since the files are already there as bower_components.

I don't want to use maps either, since it's a ripple-cordova app, and I don't want to copy uneeded files to the build

I'm kinda new to "grunt world", and I assume there might be an easy way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following grunt file.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {


    grunt.initConfig({
        bowercopy: 
        {
            options: 
            {
                // Task-specific options go here
                runBower : false
                ,nonull: true
            },
             development: 
             {
                options: {
                    destPrefix: "www"
                },
                files: {
                    // Keys are destinations (prefixed with `options.destPrefix`)
                    // Values are sources (prefixed with `options.srcPrefix`); One source per destination
                    // e.g. 'bower_components/chai/lib/chai.js' will be copied to 'test/js/libs/chai.js'
                    '/Scripts/thirdParty/jquery.js': 'jquery/dist/jquery.js'
                }
            },
             production: 
             {
                options: {
                    destPrefix: "www"
                },
                files: {
                    '/Scripts/thirdParty/jquery.js': 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                 }


               }    

    }

    });


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bowercopy');



grunt.registerTask('buildDevelopment', ['bowercopy:development']);

grunt.registerTask('buildProduction', ['bowercopy:production']);

grunt.registerTask('default', ['buildDevelopment']);


}
```

And following run.

```
$ grunt
Running "bowercopy:development" (bowercopy) task
bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js -> www/Scripts/thirdParty/jquery.js

Done, without errors.

$ grunt buildProduction
Running "bowercopy:production" (bowercopy) task
bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js -> www/Scripts/thirdParty/jquery.js

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: Hi Atilla, this is exactly what I "came up with after some research"

I wondered if there was a way to pass variables, so that I could declare the files only once, and read a suffix variable though (either .min.js or .js) to avoid duplicating the files

Comment: @LuizRolim :))) and If it is useful for you, I would appreciate if you accept it as answer.

Comment: its, useful, and I marked it as useful.

Ill just wait a bit to see if somebody comes up with the "unified" way, but I´m starting to doubt there´s such.